# How to Set/Update State of StatefulWidget from other StatefulWidget in stack Flutter?

Tags: flutter

am using something like that

```
class OpenPage extends StatefulWidget {
 @override
_OpenPageState createState() => _OpenPageState();
 }

class _OpenPageState extends State<OpenPage> {
int id= 0;

 }
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
   classOne(), //id changed here
   classTwo(), //here data depends on id

  ],
 );
}
```

where classOne and classTwo are StatefulWidget .

what am tring to do when i change id value in classOne i want it to change the classTwo where the data in the classTwo  depends on the id that change in classOne .
how could i setState classTwo  when the id in classOne  change ?

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/64965159/12111762

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the function of manipulating the id as an argument of WidgetOne. In this example WidgetOne and WidgetTwo are StatelessWidget but it should also work for StatelessWidget

```
class OpenPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _OpenPage createState() => _OpenPage();
}

class _OpenPage extends State<OpenPage > {
  int id = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        WidgetOne(
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              id++;
            });
          },
        ),
        WidgetTwo(
          id: id,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class WidgetOne extends StatelessWidget {
  final VoidCallback onPressed;

  const WidgetOne({Key key, this.onPressed}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return IconButton(
      icon: Icon(Icons.add),
      onPressed: onPressed,
    );
  }
}

class WidgetTwo extends StatelessWidget {
  final int id;
  const WidgetTwo({Key key, this.id}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(id.toString());
  }
}
```