# Calling methods of StatefulWidgets in a list from another StatefulWidget in Flutter

Tags: list, flutter, widget, key, stateful

I have a list with custom widgets, which I render in a ListView.builder.

Now i want to call a method from a special widget in my list, to for example change the Title in this widget.

I thought something like:

```
myListOfWidgets[0].performSomething();
```

would work, but this is not the case.

By using google i found a lot of articles mensioning **GlobalKeys**, but i have no plan, how this should work with a list of widgets. Every child widget have it's own state.

If you need more informations about my problem, just ask.

Comment: I think you are looking for something like this.? https://stackoverflow.com/a/64965159/12111762

Comment: with `GlobalKey` you can use `currentState` property for example

Comment: @pskink do i set the same globalkey for all widgets? How do i differentiate these when i call them up? Do you happen to have an example?

Comment: @pskink thanks for this information. What do you mean with rebuild the Listview? I tried editing the public variables, but i only can call the setstate of my parent, so my child widgets dont show the new data until i save in my IDE.

Comment: `ListView.builder` is built by some parent `StatefulWidget`, now if you want to change (for example `title`) some property of one item, call `setState` which rebuilds the `ListView` and that in turn rebuilds that item with new `title`

Comment: I tried it, but it do not rebuild widgets in which i changed the title, it keeps them, and if i add one, it will render the new one, but the old ones are still the same, without the changed title

Comment: Thank you very much, but I don't want to call setstate after a click event, but after a value has changed.  I have now implemented it with a ValueListenableBuilder, which does not work for lists, but I will look at providers later

Comment: it does not matter, you can call `setState` after a value has changed too